# Laravel Modal Not Returning Data

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am not sure why I am not getting value in Laravel controller from modal. Please help me find it out.

But, I am using the same code for other modal and controller. It's working, and it's returning values in attribute without any issue.

I am using Laravel 8 with php 8.1;

[image]

Below is my codes.

**app\Http\Controllers\Admin\MpdController.php**

```
public function edit(mpd $mpd)
{
    dd($mpd);
}
```

**app\Models\admin\mpd.php**

```
use App\Models\taxcategories;
class mpd extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $table = 'purchdata';

    protected $primaryKey = 'sno';

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'approved_at',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'sno',
        'supplier',
        'stockid',
        'price',
        'discount',
        'disc_flag',
        'tax_category',
        'preferred',
        'createby',
        'modifiedby',
        'approvedby',
        'history',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the tax_category that owns the maintainpurchasingdata
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function tax_category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(taxcategories::class, 'tax_category', 'taxrate');
    }

}
```

**routes\web.php**

```
Route::resource('maintainpurchase', 'MpdController');
```

Comment: attributes: [] -> the return result is null

Comment: Yes it's showing attributes: [] -> null but I have values in db.

Comment: You can try $query = $mpd::all(); dd($query);

Comment: Yes, it's returning 2 arrays. Also, if I select like $query = mpd::where('sno', $sno)->limit(1)->get(); it is working. But, I am unable to call like public function edit(mpd $mpd) it's returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route model binding will automatically determine a variable name based on the name before it

For example: `Route::resource('images', 'ImageController')`

Will expect `Image $image` in the controller.

Use `php artisan route:list` and look for the value between the brackets and change the

```
public function edit(mpd $mpd)
```

to

```
public function edit(mpd $THEVALUEBETWEENTHEBRACKETS)
```

Or alter the parameter name with the parameter function on the route resource definition

```
Route::resource('maintainpurchase', 'MpdController')->parameter('VALUEBETWEENTHEBRACKET', 'mpd');
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you… It's worked for me. You're my lifesaver.